# IBM Mobile Application Platform Pattern Type 5.0: Error when deploying an SQL Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I instantiate the "IBM Mobile Application Platform Pattern Type 5.0" with my worklight project ( 2 wlapp and 4 adapters ). One of my adapter is not deployed on the worklight console even if all is green in the VAP.
Here is the error I can found in the log files:

```
deploy_wl_adapter:
     [echo] worklight_context=d-ae4e9b49-478a-4f0e-99e1-e6ad4886c1d9/CustomerCentricity/
     [echo] adapter=/opt/IBM/worklight/artifact/DBAdapter.adapter
[adapter-deployer] Mar 29, 2013 12:32:48 PM com.worklight.ant.deployers.AbstractDeployerTask logDeployResponse
[adapter-deployer] SEVERE: ERROR
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

If I try to deploy the adapter directly on the worklight console, I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your adapter use a realm which do not define in the authentication.xml
Can you deploy your adapter in the local worklight console?
Such as locahost:8080/console

Comment: My realm was defined but it seems it was missing a <TestAppAuthenticity/> for the concerned securityTest in the file authenticationConfig.xml. So this problem seems to be solved. Thks.